# Highcharts: Dynamically change / add axis attributes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a number of highcharts which all contain the same default framework.  To update the dynamic elements of the charts, I have been creating new objects and referencing them within a function call which draws the chart.

This has worked fine until I have started trying to make the axis labels dynamic (some charts require dual axis).  I have included a jsfiddle which shows the dynamic structure I am working with and an example of the same chart hard coded.  Can someone tell me why this might not be working?

https://jsfiddle.net/jeo3y1rx/

Example of Object:

```
yAxis = {
    'dollars': function () { 
        var yAxis = { 
            title: { 
                text: "Burdened Dollars" 
            }
        }
        return yAxis;
    }
};
```

Example of how this is referenced in the highcharts object:

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['FY Total']
    },
    yAxis: yAxis.dollars,
    series: [{
        name: 'YTD Plan',
        data: [1000]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'YTD Actual',
        data: [900]
    }]
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Passing a function reference works for other config components?

Comment: Did you mean to evaluate the function `yAxis: yAxis.dollars(),`?

Comment: @Mark - Fantastic. I knew I was overlooking something which was sitting right in front of me.  I was not evaluating it with the parens. yAxis.dollars() worked perfectly. Can you submit this an answer and I will mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln4vkhq1/).

As you are declaring "dollars" as a function which return the values, you will have to call it like `yAxis: yAxis.dollars(),`

JS code:

```
var yAxis = {
    'dollars': function () { 
        var yAxis = { 
            title: { 
                text: "Burdened Dollars" 
            }
        };
        return yAxis;
    }
};

$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['FY Total']
        },
        yAxis: yAxis.dollars(),//call it like this
        series: [{
            name: 'YTD Plan2',
            data: [1000]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'YTD Actual',
            data: [900]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an old post, but I'll accept the answer.  Mark had made the same suggestion, which was obviously simple oversight on my part.  Thanks for working up a demo.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a function as an attribute that way in highcharts. However, you can use the highcharts API after the chart is loaded:

```
chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
        text: "Burdened Dollars"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-settitle/

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts 3.0 release allows to change axis dynamically by update() function

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update()